# Selenium IDE Parse stored attribute

Tags: selenium-ide, html-content-extraction

I am very new to programming and am trying to work my way through creating automated testing in Selenium IDE.

I have figured out how to save an attribute using the "storeAttribute" command..

**Command**: storeAttribute 
**Target**: link=${projectlabel}@onclick 
**Value**: objectID

It then stores the following variable: 
 "parent.loadPod('time_pod','time/index.cfm?action=viewPTE&objectID=2010860')"

I need to extract **only the objectID part** (those 7 numbers) and store them under a new variable name.

Can anyone walk me through how that would be done?  Or if it is even possible?

Thanks,
Orli 
Orli.Yatziv@gmail.com

Comment: I have been playing with the code and thought I could try something like: javascript{$longname.substr(67,7)} but I keep getting an error. :0(

Comment: Me again.. I almost have it .. javascript{storedVars['longname'].substring(66,74)} the problem now is I need to clean up the "s..

Comment: Last time..  I consulted a friend and he suggested I replace .substring with .match  This allows the number to change and grow and I will still get all of the numbers.  :0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Command**: storeEval
**Target**: storedVars['longname'].match(/objectID=(\d+)/)[1]
**Value**: objectID

Note: you can post an answer to your own question if you've already figured it out.